# Android App Architecture: how to share behavior between all screens

Tags: java, android, architecture, multiple-inheritance

Hi fellow Android coders,

that's a problem I struggle with every time when I make a new app. Imagine you have sub classes of Activity, ListActivity and MapActivity in your app. Now I want that every screen has the same options menu showing up when the user clicks the menu button. So I made a BaseActivity with that behavior. But because Java doesn't allow multiple inheritance I have to write three BaseActivities for every type of Activity. That is ugly because I have three times the same code... The only solution I can think of is make some of the behavior static in one of those BaseActivities and refer to that in the other BaseActivites. But there are still a lot of duplicates... Anyone has a more elegant solution for that problem?

Cheers

Comment: Why not use a ListView and a MapView in a normal Activity? That way you can use your single BaseActivity.

Comment: @Niek: You must use `MapView` in a `MapActivity`. Your point about `ListView`, though, is certainly good, and since relatively few apps need to embed a map, using one subclass of `Activity` can get you most of the way there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is one of the trade-offs for a single-inheritance language. Rather than duplicating code through inheriting various Activity sub-classes use a delegate. This is also called inheritance by delegation. You will get the features of multiple inheritance without the liabilities.

This is a accomplished by creating a delegate class that has all the shared functionality you'd like then having the "super" class call the delegate. This will still require a small level of copy-and-paste code but it will be minimal. Wikipedia has a good example of the [Delegation pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delegation_pattern#Java_examples).  If you have a background in C# this form of delegation is similar but not restricted to single methods and for more than events.

Comment: that's basically the same like calling static methods of the BaseActivity like I mentioned. But I guess that's the most elegant pattern you can use in that case. Thank you.

Comment: Its somewhat similar but there are certain drawbacks to static methods that a delegate won't have.  The single most important is inheritance, as static methods cannot be overriden. I would also argue that it is better overall design.

Comment: Makes sense. Will use delegate pattern from now on. Thanks!